# Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFinalProduct()

Tags: magento2

I have many issues in the error log file that I don't understand. I didn't found any info on this specific issue anywhere.

There is the error :

> [:error] [pid 23390] [client 78.235.181.108:52380] PHP Fatal error: 
>   Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getFinalProduct() on null in
>   /data/www/mystore/prod/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/CustomerData/Wishlist.php:135\nStack
>   trace:\n#0
>   /data/www/mystore/prod/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/CustomerData/Wishlist.php(120):
>   Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist->getItemData(Object(Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item))\n#1
>   /data/www/mystore/prod/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/CustomerData/Wishlist.php(77):
>   Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist->getItems()\n#2
>   /data/www/mystore/prod/vendor/magento/module-customer/CustomerData/SectionPool.php(79):
>   Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist->getSectionData()\n#3
>   /data/www/mystore/prod/vendor/magento/module-customer/CustomerData/SectionPool.php(60):
>   Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPool->getSectionDataByNames(Array)\n#4
>   /data/www/mystore/prod/vendor/magento/module-customer/Controller/Section/Load.php(77):
>   Magento\Customer\CustomerData\SectionPool->getSectionsData(Array,
>   false)\n#5 /data/ww in
>   /data/www/mystore/prod/vendor/magento/module-wishlist/CustomerData/Wishlist.php
>   on line 135

, referer:

The wishlist feature is the basic one from Magento (no extension should overwrite that on our website).

Do you have any idea about this problem ?

Answer (score 2):

Many themes override this Class. The error comes because they are not compatible with the latest magento version as 'itemResolver' param is added in new version.

To fix this issue find any file which is overriding this

> \Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist

Check for their construct for param

> \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Configuration\Item\ItemResolverInterface $itemResolver

if not  present add this param in construct.

Answer (score 1):

In the file vendor/magento/module-wishlist/CustomerData/Wishlist.php at line no 135

Need to change inside the method

```
protected function getItemData(\Magento\Wishlist\Model\Item $wishlistItem)

Change 
'image' => $this->getImageData($this->itemResolver->getFinalProduct($wishlistItem)),
To
'image' => $this->getImageData($product),
```

Comment: Sorry, I did not see your answer.
But no luck, I already have 
'image' => $this->getImageData($product),
in my file

Comment: This is not the proper solution as the error comes from $itemResolver.

Answer (score 1):

Check if you have any rewrites for class `\Magento\Wishlist\CustomerData\Wishlist` and fix conflicts.
Looks like base class constructor never runs so `$this->itemResolver` variable is null.